# Nested writable serializer to process flattened normalized request data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a nested writable serializer.

```
class GamerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  account= AccountSerializer()
  document = DocumentSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = Gamer
    fields = [
      'chosen_game',
      'gamer_experience',
      'account',
      'document'

  ]
```

This serializers is supposed to create Account object, a Gamer object related to Account as well as Document object related to Gamer.
By default the nested serializer always accepts nested objects as data like this:

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(data= {  account: {...acount}, document: {...document}, chosen_game: "Minecraft", "gamer_experience": "1 year"  }  )
```

but I want the serializer to accept normalized flattened data( we assume that names of the model attributes do not overlap). Like this :

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(data= {  account_name: '', account_type:'', document_name: '', document_file: '', chosen_game: "Minecraft", "gamer_experience": "1 year"  })
```

How can I achieve this result ?

Comment: Define ***all required*** fields in your `GamerSerializer` class

Comment: It will still require to pass a nested object instead of normalized array.

Comment: remove `account` and `document` fields

Comment: this will not make any difference